# Convert dynamic urls to static for directory listener ("Encode Explorer")

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I try to convert dynamic url to static for this directory listener: http://encode-explorer.siineiolekala.net/ 
Demo: http://encode-explorer.siineiolekala.net/explorer/index.php

The dynamic url is:
http://files.onitex.tmweb.ru/?dir=directory/subdirectory

What I want:
http://files.onitex.tmweb.ru/directory/subdirectory

I read documentation and wrote following rule in .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([\/\A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$  /?dir=$1 [L]
```

It works fine in this tester http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ 
but not on directory listener. 
I think I need reversed rule.
Could you explain me, how I can solve this problem, please?

**Update:**

My current .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$  /?dir=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/$  /?dir=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this rule in root .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$  /?dir=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/$  /?dir=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Don't test it on `htaccess.madewithlove.be`, its not really reliable. Test it on your localhost.

Comment: Thank you for answer! But it isn't work: http://files.onitex.tmweb.ru/documentation doesn't work, but http://files.onitex.tmweb.ru/?dir=documentation is work

Comment: What is location of your .htaccess and what URL did you try to test it?

Comment: /files/public_html/.htaccess - is root directory of this site (http://files.onitex.tmweb.ru).

I try to test it with http://files.onitex.tmweb.ru/documentation of http://files.onitex.tmweb.ru/documentation/subfolder

Comment: Are you sure .htaccess is enabled on your site?

Comment: I did it. Current .htaccess in my question

Comment: Done. I have `http://files.onitex.tmweb.ru/directory/subdirectory/?dir=directory/subdirectory` now.

Comment: But if i select any folder url will be broken: http://files.onitex.tmweb.ru/directory/subdirectory/?dir=directory/

Comment: That has nothing to do with these rules. If you mouse over the subdirectory link on `http://files.onitex.tmweb.ru/directory/` you will notice `http://files.onitex.tmweb.ru/directory/?dir=directory/subdirectory` that not pretty link is shown by your code/software.

Comment: Ok! I'll try to fix code. Thank you very much, you very helped me with rules.